# How $x^2$ increases by $x+\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was going through one of the topic "Introduction to Formal proof".In one example while explaining "Hypothesis" and "conclusion" got confused.

The example is as follows: If $x\geq 4$ then $2^x \geq x^2$.

While deriving conclusion article said "As $x$ grows larger than $4$, LHS $2^x$ doubles as $x$ increases by $1$ and RHS grows by ratio $x+\frac{1}{x}$".

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be (x+1)^2/x^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important insight that the RHS grows by less than a factor of two if $x\ge4$, i.e. $(x+1)^2<2\cdot x^2$ can alternatively be seen from $$ (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+\underbrace{1}_{<x}<x^2+\underbrace{3}_{<x}x<x^2+x^2=2x^2$$
(where making use of $1<x$ and $3<x$ looks very wasteful, but we don't need anything better)
or from
$$ 2x^2-(x+1)^2=x^2-2x-1=(x-1)^2-2\ge3^2-2= 7.$$